# Django Unicode- When I Use unicode functions?

Tags: python, django

I'm From Iran And I Use Persian Character. When should I use 'u', 'decode()', 'encode' and unicode()?

Comment: Uh… Your question is too vague. Give an exemple of something you want to to, and a problem you encounter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You use `decode()` and `unicode()` to *decode* the input string from its representation (for example iso-8859-2 or utf-8) and get the unicode object.

2) You use a `u` to indicate that the string is to be treated as unicode (in fact the result object is unicode type):

```
>>> foo = u'łódź'
>>> foo.__class__
<type 'unicode'>
```

3) Use the `encode()` to *encode* the input string using for example utf-8 (or any other encoding of your choice) and get the str object:

```
>>> foo = u'łódź'
>>> foo.__class__
<type 'unicode'>
>>> bar = foo.encode('utf-8')
>>> bar.__class__
<type 'str'>
```

Read through this [article about unicode in Python](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) to get better idea of string/unicode/string encoding mess.